# Persistant data with Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center

Is it possible to use Game Center to store persistant data regarding your game? so for example would I be able to store an "experience" value for players linked to a specific game, in their Game Center accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this by using different leaderboards. 
But the kind of data is very limited, and you can only increase one player's score. 
What do you want to store ? 
experience can be stored locally, even permanently with NSUserDefaults

Comment: I would prefer to store it online, rather than just on their phone. What I read in the apple Docs gave the impression that perhaps you could store data for a player on Game Center for a particular game (I'm working on a turn-based game), but I guess not then. I'll probably use parse.com then to store stuff.

Comment: @Phil, so, can you store custom data player on Game Center ?

Comment: what do you mean with 'very limited' ?